# Trying to submit a parent form using onclick event, not working

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to submit the parent form, using an "onclick" event without specifying the form's id. There is a reason for this. I am using a webfont for a button hence the "span".

My code:

```
<form action="/Index" method="post">    <p>
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" onclick="document.form.submit();" style="font-size:50px;cursor:pointer;"></span>  
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="10000"/>     
</p>
```

I have also tried:

```
onclick="this.form.submit();"
```

This also failed to work.

What is the correct code please?

Comment: What's wrong with a submit button? No script required. Only form controls (input, textarea, etc.) in a form have a *form* property by default.

Comment: How can I use a webfont when using a button element. The webfonts are activated by the class attribute. They are the "font awesome" ones. This is why I am using a span tag.

Comment: RobG, I understand where you are coming from, and most of my forms just use button tags. However this is a special use case where the user needs a webfont. Thanks for the wisdom however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.forms[0].submit()` **if you have only one form in page.**
In case if you have multiple forms on the same page then it would submit the first encountered form.

Comment: The OP could use a button in the form and then `this.form.submit()` would work. But it would work without the script too. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any other forms?

if no, try: 'document.forms[0].submit'

otherwise, add a id to the form

```
<form id="testForm" action='..'>...</form>

document.getElementById('testForm').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close your form element.

```
<form action="/Index" method="post">    
    <p>
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" onclick="document.form.submit();" style="font-size:50px;cursor:pointer;"></span>  
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="10000"/>     
    </p>
</form> /*This*/
```

Should work once you close it.

Answer (score 0):

The below strategy to submit the form would work **even if have multiple forms on the same page given that you provide a unique id to each form**. The `<form>` should be provided an `id` attribute so that specific can be targeted with the given `id` as below:

```
<form id="myFormId" action="/Index" method="post">
    <p>
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('myFormId').submit()" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" role="button" style="font-size:50px;cursor:pointer;"></span>  
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="10000"/>     
    </p>
</form>
```